# Creating a dynamic array with only location of memory in a file

Tags: c, arrays

I have some file *fp which has structs laid out in an array at an offset of 4 bytes after the file's header "header."

How would I use typecasting to read individual structs out of this array using only the location in memory?

Would it be something like this?

```
struct_name *arr = (struct_name *) &header + 4; 

struct_name x = arr[1];
```

I am doing something similar but getting a segmentation fault. Does anything need to be malloc-ed here?

Comment: your code `+4` meant `+sizeof(struct_name)*4`, not 4 byte

Comment: On which operating system? With POSIX (i.e. Linux) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) could be relevant

Comment: If you want a mem-address at `&header` + 4 bytes, you'll probably want to cast `&header` to a `char *`...

Comment: Duplicate of [Error on typecasting using struct definitions in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106958/error-on-typecasting-using-struct-definitions-in-c)?

Comment: we really need to see a (non)working piece of code not just 2 isolated lines. YOu could be almost correct, you could be totally wrong; hard to say

Answer (score 0):

The file need to be loaded in memory, for be able to cast this memory as a structure, you have two common options

- Reading all the content to a buffer (versions in C and C++ in the Sample Code).
- Mapping the file (version in C++ in the sample code using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file`). In C you could use platform specific functions ([mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) in Linux and [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761.aspx) in Windows).

Note: The size of the types of all the elements of the struct to cast must be known in compile time (no std::string, or any other type that allocate memory during runtime). You need to load in the buffer at least the memory of the array to cast and iterate.

Sample Code (Tested in GCC 4.9.0 with C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

struct data {
    int a, b;
};

int main() {
    // C version
    FILE* fp = fopen("E:\\save.txt", "rb");
    if (!fp)
        return -1;

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size0 = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char* cbuffer = (char*)malloc(size0);
    fread(cbuffer, 1, size0, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < size0; idx++)
        std::cout << (long)cbuffer[idx] << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    data* data0 = (data*)&cbuffer[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << data0[i].a << std::endl;
    }

    delete cbuffer;
    // End C version

    // C++ Version
    std::ifstream ifs("E:\\save.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

    if (!ifs.good())
        return -1;

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    long long size = ifs.tellg();

    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(size);
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    ifs.read((char*)&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    ifs.close();

    for (auto d : buffer)
        std::cout << (long)d << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    data* data1 = (data*)&buffer[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << data1[i].a << std::endl;
    }
    // End C++ Version

    // C++ Mapped File
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mmfile("E:\\save.txt");

    for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < mmfile.size(); idx++)
        std::cout << (long)mmfile.data()[idx] << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    data* data2 = (data*)mmfile.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << data2[i].b << std::endl;
    }
    mmfile.close();
    // End C++ Mapped File

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as **C**.

Comment: the OP indicates C not C++

Answer (score 0):

The `(struct_name*)&header` in your question implies a fundamental misconception.

Unless this variable stores the entire data of the file (and not just the header), using its address is probably a very bad idea, because the rest of the data is not going to "come after it".

So the answer below assumes that you have read the entire file into memory pointed by `char* data`.

---

Theoretically, you could do something like this:

```
element_struct  val;
element_struct* ptr = (element_struct*)(data+sizeof(header_struct)+4);

// Read the n-th element (starting from 0)
val = ptr[n];
```

However, this would be potentially unsafe, due to unaligned memory access operations.

---

Therefore, here is a safer way of doing it:

```
element_struct val;
char* ptr = data+sizeof(header_struct)+4;

// Read the n-th element (starting from 0)
memcpy(&val,ptr+n*sizeof(element_struct),sizeof(element_struct));
```

---

In addition to the above, you will need to make sure that the padding added to your structures by the compiler, accurately reflects the way in which your data is laid out within the file.

Comment: Thanks - but what does header_struct_name refer to, and why wouldn't you use &data instead of data? Also, do I have to cast it to (struct name *)(char *) if data is a void pointer?

Comment: @marchon: `header_struct_name` is the type of your `header` variable.

Comment: Using this approach is still giving me a seg fault: SectionHeader sec_hdr;
        int j = 0; // initial byte offset

        for (int i = 0; i < hdr.num_section_headers; i++) {

                memcpy(&sec_hdr, sec_hdrs + j, sec_hdr.size);
                if (sec_hdr.type == FUNC) break;
                j += sizeof(sec_hdr);
        }

Comment: @marchon: You should probably use `j++` instead of `j += sizeof(sec_hdr)`.